# Error al desplegar en vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, vercel

quiero desplegar el front de una web app hecha con React js (vite) pero me esta dando este problema y no estaria entendiendo que es lo que esta mal. La app funciona perfectamente. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar

Link al repositorio: https://github.com/guidomora/CalendarApp.git

copio el codigo de ese componente:

```
export const getEnvVariables = () => {
  import.meta.env

  return {
    ...import.meta.env
  };
};
```

[image: deploy error]

Muchas gracias!

Comment: guardaste lo que esta en el archivo .env en las variable de entorno en vercel ?

Comment: si, guarde la de mi backend en desarrollo y tambien la de produccion que seria el backend desplegado, probe de dejar solo la de produccion y me sigue dando error